# Service in authorize.net similar to paypal

Tags: paypal, authorize.net, paypal-ipn

I have implemented IPN in paypal which updates about the payment in our server's database.I want to know that is there a  similar functionality in authorize.net?
Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes,

it's called silent post. Paypals documentation is better though.

Here is a good blog post.

http://www.johnconde.net/blog/all-about-authorize-nets-silent-post/